# gcp bash script in cloud shell terminal for Org policies

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I would like realized inventory of GCP Org policies which are SET in my organization top folders, so I want to use bash script in my cloud shell terminal.
Code below works but I want use folder "DisplayName" and not folder ID.
DisplayName can be retrieve  with this cmd `gcloud beta resource-manager folders list --organization=XXXXX--format=value"(ID, DISPLAY_NAME)`but it is difficult to organize result later in one table

```
#!/bin/bash
for folder in $(gcloud beta resource-manager folders list --organization=XXXXX --format="value(ID)")
  do   
     echo $folder
      gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies list --folder=$folder
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to either `organization` or `folder` but, the following should work.

The *trick* is to use `--format=csv[no-heading]` to provide a more readily 'parseable` values:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ORGANIZATION="..."

PAIRS=$(\
  gcloud beta resource-manager folders list \
  --organization=${ORGANIZATION} \
  --format="csv[no-heading](ID,displayName)")

for PAIR in ${PAIRS}
do   
  IFS=, read ID DISPLAY_NAME <<< ${PAIR}
  echo ${DISPLAY_NAME}
  gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies list \
  --folder=${ID}
done
```

Comment: It works, thanks I just modified some character to works

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
ORGANIZATION="XXXXXX"
PAIRS=$(gcloud beta resource-manager folders list --organization=${ORGANIZATION} --format="csv[no-heading](ID,DISPLAY_NAME)")
for PAIR in ${PAIRS}
do   
  IFS=, read ID DISPLAY_NAME <<< ${PAIR}
  echo ${DISPLAY_NAME}
  gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies list --folder=${ID}
done
```

Comment: Your `--format="csv[no-heading](ID,DISPLAY_NAME)"` looks incorrect. I think `DISPLAY_NAME` is not part of the response. It's probably (!) `displayName`. (I corrected my answer r/DisplayName/displayName too, per: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/folders#Folder

Comment: but the result of gcloud command "gcloud beta resource-manager folders list --organization=XXXX" produce these column name "DISPLAY_NAME, PARENT_NAME and ID", I should take column name or REST in script ?

Comment: You should take the response object values. You may either look the field names up using e.g. APIs Explorer or you can use `--format=yaml` or `--format=json` to see the output listed in those formats with the correct field name.